# Finding a root of a fractional equation

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, fractions

I want to find a root of the following equation
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{p_ia}{(1-xp_i)^2}=1
\end{equation}
where $x$ is variable with constraint $x>0$, $a$ and $p_i$ are some known positive number.
There might be many roots.
Is there any way to solve that equation?(or numerical method)
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can only solve it analytically for m=1, 2. For m=3 the solution (which I checked with Mathematica) is a 6th order polynomial and so on for higher m. Actually the order of the polynomial you'd have to solve is 2m. As for numerical solutions, any implementation of Newton–Raphson's method should work. In Mathematica/Wolfram Language, just use the function Solve.

Comment: I know we can just express as 2m order polynomial, but is there any more simple way to solve that problem? I pop out this thought because it has a special structure. My target is to express $x$ as function of $p_i$s and $a$

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the problem, let us first change notations? Using $b_i=\frac a {p_i}$ and $c_i=\frac 1 {p_i}$, you want to find the zero's of function
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{b_i}{(x-c_i)^2}-1$$ which will show $2m$ roots among which some ( or none) would be real. Assuming, without any loss of generality, that the $c_i$'s are ordered $(c_1<c_2<\cdots<c_{m-1}<c_m)$ and different, there are potentially two roots between two asymptotes.

Suppose that your search for the roots between $c_k$ and $c_{k+1}$, amke the problem more continuous considering in this interval
$$g_k(x)=(x-c_k)^2(x-c_{k+1})^2 f(x)-(x-c_k)^2(x-c_{k+1})^2 $$ that is to say
$$g_k(x)=(x-c_k)^2(x-c_{k+1})^2\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \frac{b_i}{(x-c_i)^2}+
b_k(x-c_{k+1})^2+$$
$$b_{k+1}(x-c_k)^2+(x-c_k)^2(x-c_{k+1})^2\sum_{i=k+2}^{m} \frac{b_i}{(x-c_i)^2}-(x-c_k)^2(x-c_{k+1})^2$$

At its boundaries
$$g_k(c_k)=b_k(c_{k+1}-c_{k})^2 \qquad \text{and} \qquad g_k(c_{k+1})=b_{k+1}(c_{k+1}-c_{k})^2$$ and you see that , in the range $c_k \leq x \leq c_{k+1}$, if  $b_{k}\,b_{k+1} <0 $,  function $g_k(x)$ looks like a straight line; otherwise  function $g_k(x)$ *"looks more or less like a parabola"*.

If we are in the "nice" case, we can use as an estimate
$$x_0=\frac{b_{k+1}\,c_k- b_k\,c_{k+1}} {b_{k+1}-b_{k} }$$ and Newton method will converge like a charm.

To follow if you wish.

Comment: @Chc. Because I multiplied everything by $(x-c_{i})^2(x-c_{k+1})^2$ including the $1$.  Sen me a set of $a$ and $p_i$'s for a reasonable $m$ and I shall show you in details. Yes, the roots of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are the same.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to do newline in comment. I just delete the original one.
$p_i$'s are eigenvalues of a $m$ by $m$positive semi definite matrix. In my algorithm, the matrix are data-dependent, I can just ganrantee that they are all positive. $a$ is a arbitrary positive number in my case, depend on parameters of my algorithm, you can assume that $a$ is close to 1.

Comment: m is one of dimension of some image data, you can assume that m = 32, or 64,

Comment: @Chc. OK, let us try $m=32$. Give me the other parameters $a$ and $p_i$. By the way, forget an expression.

Comment: I just run a test case,  $p_i$'s can be 13 
          14
          15
          19
          21
          21
          23
          24
          25
          30
          33
          34
          38
          45
          50
          58
          72
          79
         100
         117
         130
         136
         158
         235
         327
         524
         646
         696
        1261
        2412
        9334
       51135 after just round off, and $a$ you can simply assume some number between (0,10]

Comment: Yes, that can be a feasible $a$, thank you for your help!!